# Deploying OneClick Applications With PSAKE/CommandLine

Tags: .net, command-line, msbuild

I've recently set up a OneClick application which works fine when deploying from Visual Studio IDE. However, I want to deploy using our build server using PSAKE.

I've got the solution to build and publish by using the following command from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx)

> msbuild /target:publish /property:BootstrapperEnabled=false

but the ".exe.config.deploy" files don't get generated.

I've found some documentation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41921/How-to-build-sign-and-deploy-a-ClickOnce-applicati) which states to use Mage utility but I've seen recent questions around stock overflow where people are asking how to do this from the command line and no one has said it's impossible.

Basically, my question is do I need to use Mage Utility or can the OneClick publish be performed in the command?